# How to disable dependency resolution in Poetry?

Tags: python-poetry

I'm using Poetry to manage my Python dependencies.

However, the delay in adding a new dependency is unbearable (often 1-3 h spent in package "resolving dependencies")

This is partly because I work in data science where it's not uncommon to have many "large" packages. Eg. Pandas, Sklearn, Tensorflow, Torch, FastAI, RapidAPI, Jupyter, IPython, ...

It is also not uncommon to install or update a new dependency fairly often.

Is there any practical way to either disable or speed up the dependency resolution? I want to keep using poetry for it's support of pyproject.toml, but I can't justify spending 10h/week waiting for package installs that would take 20min using pip and requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful issue thread on the poetry Github repo on this point, which includes a number of suggestions on how to speed up dependency resolution: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2094

If you use Ubuntu disabling IPv6 often does the trick:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```